# Python X-axis nearest point

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

I am trying to come up with a simple algorithm without importing modules where you have several x-axis points like

```
d = [-5, -3.5, -2.8, -0.6, 1.2, 3.4, 5.6]
```

and where you prompt the user to enter a certain point, the program should give the closest point to the entered value by the user,since there are negative values which can possibly be closest I just need a general idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two steps:

1. Use the [`bisect` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) to find the index for the nearest lower value
2. Use the absolute distance between that nearest lower value and the next, higher value to pick one of those two.

This is a O(logN) algorithm; for N points at most log N steps have to be executed. Compare that to sorting by absolute distance, which takes O(NlogN) to find the nearest point, or using `min()` taking O(N).

Take into account that step one can pick an index at the start or end, where there is no lower or higher second point:

```
import bisect

def nearest(x, d):
    index = bisect.bisect(d, x)
    if not index:
        return d[index]  # left-most x coordinate
    if index == len(d):
        return d[-1]  # right-most x coordinate
    return min(d[index - 1:index + 1], key=lambda v: abs(v - x))
```

Demo:

```
>>> import bisect
>>> def nearest(x, d):
...     index = bisect.bisect(d, x)
...     if not index:
...         return d[index]  # left-most x coordinate
...     if index == len(d):
...         return d[-1]  # right-most x coordinate
...     return min(d[index - 1:index + 1], key=lambda v: abs(v - x))
... 
>>> d = [-5, -3.5, -2.8, -0.6, 1.2, 3.4, 5.6]
>>> nearest(10, d)
5.6
>>> nearest(-10, d)
-5
>>> nearest(0, d)
-0.6
>>> nearest(3, d)
3.4
```

For completeness sake, the `min()` approach is:

```
min(d, key=lambda v: abs(v - x))
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but iam trying to find away without importing modules,assuming that iam not allowed to import,i was told there is away.

Comment: @aero: the bisect module source is linked from the documentation; reimplement your own `bisect` function, it is exceedingly simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
min(array, key=lambda x: abs(x)-point)
```

What the above code does is returns the minimum value of the absolute value of each point and subtracting the user input point from it.